# How to send MultiPart Request without calling drain?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, multipart, aiohttp

Since version 3.0.0 of `aiohttp` [the `drain` method of `StreamResponse` was deprecated](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/2483).
But in [the documentation of sending multipart request](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/multipart.html#sending-multipart-requests) `drain` method is still used. And it's unobvious how to use `write` instead of `drain` in this case. Could someone help out?

```py
my_boundary = 'some-boundary'
response = web.StreamResponse(
    status=200,
    reason='OK',
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary={}'.format(my_boundary)
    }
)
while True:
    frame = get_jpeg_frame()
    with MultipartWriter('image/jpeg', boundary=my_boundary) as mpwriter:
        mpwriter.append(frame, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        })
        await mpwriter.write(response, close_boundary=False)
    await response.drain()  # should it be await response.write_eof() ?
```